# Compare multiple fields using SearchCursor dictionary and UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I have two feature classes. I need to transfer attributes from a point feature class to a line feature class based on a combination of fields. They do not have matching field names. Here is an example of what I want to compare between my SearchCursor dictionary and my UpdateCursor table:

if row[0] in intdict AND row[2] in intdict != row[2] AND row[3] in intdict == row[3] AND row[4] in intdict = row[4] THEN row[6] = row[1] in intdict

```
intdict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(interSectPts,['FID_ADDRSTAND','STREET', 'POINT_X','POINT_Y'])}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(addrLyr,['FID_ADDRSTAND','STREET','STARTX_2','STARTY_2', 'ENDX_2', 'ENDY_2','FROM_','TO_']) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         if (row[0] in intdict):
            update row with value
            update row with value
            update row with value
            etc.....
```

To add context, I am changing the values of a road segment in the TO_ and FROM_ columns to show the street names of intersecting roads. For example a segment named 'Main St' could intersect '1st st' on the west end and '2nd st' on the east end...thus the attribute table would look like:

```
STREET   |    FROM_     |     TO_
Main St  |   1st St     |    2nd St
```

I basically an comparing the x,y coordinates of the intersection point feature class and its street names with the x,y of the starting and ending coordinates of street segments. When an intersection occurs, I am grabbing the values of the street name. My primary question is how to structure my 'if' in the update cursor...the rest, I feel like I could do....

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work,

```
intdict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(interSectPts,['FID_ADDRSTAND','STREET', 'POINT_X','POINT_Y'])}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(addrLyr,['FID_ADDRSTAND','STREET','STARTX_2','STARTY_2', 'ENDX_2', 'ENDY_2','FROM_','TO_']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if (row[0] in intdict and intdict[row[0]][0] != row[1]):
            # pto = start
            if intdict[row[0]][1] == row[2] and intdict[row[0]][2] == row[3]:
                # from = street
                row[6] = intdict[row[0]][0]
            # pto = end
            if intdict[row[0]][1] == row[4] and intdict[row[0]][2] == row[5]:
                # to = street
                row[7] = intdict[row[0]][0]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

One last thing, remember that you can filter the result using `where_clause`, so in this case you could avoid checking `if row[0] in intdict` and most important you get only the result you want to update.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(
    addrLyr,
    ['FID_ADDRSTAND','STREET','STARTX_2','STARTY_2', 'ENDX_2', 'ENDY_2','FROM_','TO_'],
    where_clause="'FID_ADDRSTAND' IN ({})".format(','.join(intdict.keys()))
) as cursor:
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your example (before adding the where clause)...it didn't work but I think I can sort out why if you can explain: intdict[row[0]][1] == row[2] . What is that line of code saying? I dont understand the [row[0]][1].

Comment: `row[0]` is the key in `intdict`, and `[1]` indexes `POINT_X` .. what was the problem?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I am still trying to get the code to work.....I don't think it is establishing a relationship with the key field.....when I ran the code, it completed successfully but didn't update the FROM/TO field where there are obviously intersections. I am going to keep working at it this morning.

Comment: Ok, from what I can tell, your code worked just fine. The issue was the intersectPts feature class had  multiple coincident points. A point for each segment at the intersection --- so in most circumstances, it had 3 points per intersection. I am going to first identify the points that have matching x,y and streetname to the segments, remove them from the feature class, and then create a dictionary from remaining points. I'll update my post if that works.

Comment: That would be great

Comment: ok, I still haven't figured this out. I cannot do the steps I mentioned above because I actually do need all of those intercept points.....I cannot understand why it doesn't work except to think that the code works but I am asking it the wrong question: \\if (intdict[row[0]][1] == row[2] and intdict[row[0]][2] == row[3] and intdict[row[0]][0] != row[1]):

Comment: Unless the reason is because the value does exist and I need to get the one that doesn't match....for example: I have three points at an intersection where airport rd meets main st. So, I have three points with the exact same (x,y). Two streetnames have airport rd and matching x,y; the other point (which is the perpendicular road name that I want to populate my FROM_ field, has main st with matching (x,y)...you gave me code that finds the matching (x,y) and then populates with the street name result....@cabesuon

Comment: I need the road that doesn't match the current segment street name. I tried adding the "and intdict[row[0]][0] != row[1]" to the end of your suggestion but it gives me zero results.....because the statement is true in two circumstances but doesn't seem to care about the third circumstance. @cabesuon

Comment: Ok I think I understand, then the condition you are trying should work. I don't understand why 3 is the common case, shouldn't be 2? I mean in most cases a corner is between two streets, right?. I update the answer with the condition.

Comment: I second cabesuons question: shouldn't there generally be 2 pts at each intersection? Or four (one for each if two segments for two streets)? I'm not understanding why 'airport' has two pts but 'main' only has one?. Regardless, it seems that your added conditional should work. I suggest either a) adding a bunch of print statements so that you can see what values you are working with or preferably b) using a debugger to step through your code one line at a time. Not sure if you're working in an ide, but if nothing else there is always the pdb module

Comment: @cabesuon Thanks for you help. I still haven't had any success. Even with your changes. I added messages to  track progress. The first 'if' finds values that meet the criteria. However, it then says it finds no matching (x,y) coordinates for the two remaining conditions. I'm going insane. To answer your question on why 3...In the street data, every segment is split at an intersection. So, I have a point for where a segment ends, one begins, and at the perpendicular.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for you suggestions. I think I answered your question and have tried debugging with print statements and debugger, as you suggested. I've been doing both all along. Just not having any luck getting the code to work.

Comment: Can you update your question and add your code showing the conditional structure you are using?

Comment: Is it possible that the xy coordinate values are slightly different between the feature classes? Maybe you need to account for a margin of error? Are they both the same data type? If one is numbers represented as a string they may look the same but not match?

Comment: @Nick I must be lacking a fundamental understanding here on the dictionary -- that is my guess for why the code isn't working. I wholeheartedly think I am the problem. In the 'intersectPts', the field 'FID_ADDRSTAND' is not unique. It is the field that tracks which of the segments OBJECTIDs in 'addrLyr' has an intersect. It seems like the dictionary would want a UID  for objects. When I switch to 'OBJECTID', instead of 'FID_ADDRSTAND' in the intersectPts, it makes it past the first 'if' but that is as far as it gets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104219/discussion-between-dbchic-noob-and-nick).